# Android manifest XML provider tag. android:authorities

Tags: android, manifest, provider, authority

I have been going through the NotePad sample application for android-17 when I came across this tag in the manifest XML file:

```
    <provider android:name="NotePadProvider"
        android:authorities="com.google.provider.NotePad"
        android:exported="false">
        <grant-uri-permission android:pathPattern=".*" />
    </provider>
```

I looked up the defenition and I see that `com.google.provider.NotePad` is being listed as one of the authorities for the provider. I am assuming that `NotePadProvider` is referencing the class `NotePadProvider` defined in the `NotePadProvider.java` file but I want to ask if that is really the case to make sure I am on the right track.

Also I am wondering what exactly is `com.google.provider.NotePad` and where is it defined and what is the purpose of `com.google.provider.NotePad` and what does it mean that `com.google.provider.NotePad` is the authority for the provider exactly.

Comment: If you are setting the authoritie for the NotePad and want to set it to "Google", it musn't end with .NotePad, I think you want to set android:authorities="com.google.Notepad.provider" since the package naming convenion is com.company_name.app_name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html).

> **Content providers** are one of the primary building blocks of Android
>   applications, providing content to applications. They encapsulate data
>   and provide it to applications through the single ContentResolver
>   interface. A content provider is only required if you need to share
>   data between multiple applications. For example, the contacts data is
>   used by multiple applications and must be stored in a content
>   provider. If you don't need to share data amongst multiple
>   applications you can use a database directly via SQLiteDatabase.

Actually, `com.google.provider.NotePad` is a class that implements the `ContentProvider`.

From [`<provider>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element.html):

> **android:authorities** 
>   A list of one or more URI authorities that
>   identify data offered by the content provider. Multiple authorities
>   are listed by separating their names with a semicolon. To avoid
>   conflicts, authority names should use a Java-style naming convention
>   (such as com.example.provider.cartoonprovider). Typically, it's the
>   name of the ContentProvider subclass that implements the provider

Comment: I have a problem when I'm providing two authorities. Even though the documentation says to separate them with a semicolon it doesn't work. I can't even build the project if there is a semicolon existent. How can I set multiple authorities?
for instance, this does not work: android:authorities="${applicationId}.MainActivity;${applicationId}.contactview.ContactViewWithViewPagerTabActivity"